# Determining whether $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sin(n\pi/12)}{\ln n}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having issues with determining convergence/divergence of alternating series that use sine and cosine. I'm perfectly clear of how to handle ones with $(-1)^{n+1}$ (and similar) by performing the Absolute Convergence Test and by applying Leibnitz's theorem, but sine and cosine ones are a totally different story.

I simply don't know where to start on this one, for example.

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sin\dfrac{n\pi}{12}}{\ln n}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Yeah, I'll take your advice definitely, just need some more time to get to know things.

Comment: I've used MathJax to display the series. Feel free to make the rest of the post less wordy, or to clarify whether there's anything you want evaluated besides that one series.

Comment: Thank You! No, that'd be pretty much it I'm interested in right now.

Comment: Observe $\displaystyle\sin(n\pi/12)$ is periodic so its sum cannot be greater than $\sum_{n=1}^{12} \sin(n\pi/{12})$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran Is that enough to prove that the partial sums are bounded? As per Dirichlet's theorem.

Comment: @Rose: Yes to be exact. You should evaluate and see the series for few values of $n$ to convince yourself though.

Comment: @YadatiKiran I'd do that for sure, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the Dirichlet's test.

For that, we observe that $\frac{1}{\log (n)}$ is decreasing and tending to $0$ as $n\to \infty.$ Next we have to show that 
$$S_M=\sum_{n=1}^{M}\sin(n\pi/12)$$ is bounded.

For this use the following equation:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin kx=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}2x\right)-\cos\left(n+\frac{1}2\right)x}{2\sin(x/2)},x\neq0,\pm\pi,\pm 2\pi,...$$

Comment: Ah, Dirichlet's theorem, I'd never think of it, thanks! Could you just explain the way you prove that the partial sums are bounded?